# Store data as numbers in a file in Python

Tags: python, string, int

I wrote a program that opens a file and read it line by line and store just the third element of each line. The problem is that, when I write those outputs into a file I need to change them as strings which is not suitable for me due to the fact that I want to do some mathematical operations on the written file later on. FYI, it also is not suitable to store it like this and use int() while reading it.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

```
with open("/home/test1_to_write", "w") as g:
    with open("/home/test1_to_read", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            a=line.split()
            number = int(a[3])
            g.write(str(number)+'\n')

g.close()
```

Comment: A file is naive and has no concept of `int`s and `str`s. Read the file and convert to int.

Comment: I guess you could try writing `chr(number)` but I doubt thats what you want either

Comment: use numpy.loadtxt or something similar if you plan on doing operations on the data later

Comment: Files always have some sort of encoding, be it a string representation of a number, fixed length binary bytes as in a little-endian 8 byte blob, or any of a thousand other choices. Your current solution is reasonable and somethlng like it is used often. Why isn't it good for you?

Comment: I have another question now. Assuming I go on with my own code and store the data as string. When I want to read it, since I have entered '\n' I received an error for using int(line)

Comment: note that `g.close()` will probably throw an error since the file is already closed by that time (can you re-close a close file object?) At the very least it's superfluous

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to tell a text file that `1` is the number one not the letter `"1"`. If you need that, consider storing the whole thing as a list instead using some sort of serial format e.g. JSON:

```
import json

with open("/home/test1_to_write.json", 'w') as outfile:
    with open("/home/test1_to_read", 'r') as infile:
        data = [int(line.split()[3]) for line in infile]
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```

You can then load the data with:

```
with open("/home/test1_to_write.json", "r") as infile:
    read_data = json.load(infile)
```

Comment: But is json better than a single column ascii file like OP is writing now?

Comment: @tdelaney `json.load(fileobj)` versus `[int(line) for line in fileobj]`. Feels like I'm just offering him a different poison. At least he gets to pick :)

Comment: I have another question now. Assuming I go on with my own code and store the data as string. When I want to read it, since I have entered '\n' I received an error for using int(line)

Comment: @CristopherVanPaul You shouldn't. `int` strips whitespace from a string before trying to convert it to integer.

Comment: @AdamSmith ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '56562719063.0\n'

Comment: @CristopherVanPaul that's because it's a string representing a float, not a string representing an int. `int(float(line))` if you need to, but that's ugly as sin and is in fact impossible to reproduce from your example code

Comment: @AdamSmith, Fair enough!